# How close is size of object in json form compared to in memory

Tags: java, json, memory, objectsize

Suppose there is object `animal` of class Animal. I want to calculate size of object `animal` inside the memory. One way I can do is to use gson to convert object into JSON form and calculate the size of string. How close would be size of this string to real object ?